# .NET Core - API Composition patttern example

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, microservices

I can’t find an example of data aggregation from several microservices with data pagination.

For example - there is a product service and a product description service. I need to build a query that will display the products with their descriptions.

```
api/products?limit=10&skip=0
api/productDescriptions?limit=10&skip=0

class Product{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get; set;} // fill from api/productDescriptions
}
```

I don't want to use `api/productDescriptions?id=1` request, because I have to process request in cycle.

I think about `api/productDescriptions?ids=1,2,3` request, but how good is that idea?

Comment: ...those look like the same service, just different endpoints.

Comment: ...do you control these services - or not? Why are you using REST-like HTTP instead of a protocol that works better for raw queries, like OData or even TDS if you feel like living dangerously?

Comment: I'm at the planning stage, just want to see a good example / best practics